# Filter rows in dplyr chain if a set of rows doesn't contain a specific word

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have the following dataset:

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="name value
stranger_things_mc Stranger_Land
stranger_things_confidence 100
stranger_things_importance 1
stranger_things_answer Stranger_Things
immigrant_crime_number 140
immigrant_crime_confidence 100
immigrant_crime_importance 3
immigrant_crime_answer 50
dog_things_mc Stranger_Land
dog_things_confidence 100
dog_things_importance 1
dog_things_answer Stranger_Things
fighting_stats_number 140
fighting_stats_confidence 100
fighting_stats_answer 50")
```

Every fourth row *should* contain three suffixes (_confidence, _importance, _answer), although sometimes it does not (as with "fighting_stats" above).  A row sometimes has an (_mc) suffix and other times it will say (_number or _slider).

I want to filter out any row that contains (_number or _slider) AS WELL AS the three rows associated with that _number or _slider column.  So, in the example above, the resulting output would be:

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="name value
stranger_things_mc Stranger_Land
stranger_things_confidence 100
stranger_things_importance 1
stranger_things_answer Stranger_Things
dog_things_mc Stranger_Land
dog_things_confidence 100
dog_things_importance 1
dog_things_answer Stranger_Things")
```

I can filter out specific columns like so:

```
final_results <- df %>% 
  filter(!str_detect(name, "_number") & !str_detect(name, "_slider"))
```

but cannot figure out how to remove all the associated columns.  The general algorithm should be:

First, locate a row with "_number" or "_slider" in the name column, and grab the text that comes before it. In the above example, that would be "fighting_stats" and "immigrant_crime." Then, delete any row that has that text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We create a grouping column based on the condition that every fourth row is a new block (`gl`), then `filter` out the groups where the `first` element of 'name' is not a `_number` or `_slider`, then `ungroup` and remove the temporary 'grp' column created

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(grp = as.integer(gl(n(), 4, n()))) %>% 
    filter(!str_detect(first(name), "_(number|slider)")) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    select(-grp)
```

#### Update

Based on the comments from the OP i.e. blocks are determined by their common prefix, then extract the first `word`, use that as grouping variable and do the `filter` as before

```
library(stringr)
df %>%
  group_by(grp = word(name, 1, sep="_")) %>% 
  filter(!str_detect(first(name), "_(number|slider)"))
```

and the `ungroup` part remains the same as previous

If there are repeating prefixes i.e. non-adjacent prefixes and needs to be considered as separate blocks, then use `rleid` from `data.table` to create the grouping variable

```
df %>%
  group_by(grp = rleid(word(name, 1, sep="_"))) %>%
  filter(!str_detect(first(name), "_(number|slider)"))
```

Comment: Very clever.  Thank you!  One issue is that, there's no guarantee that every fourth row is 'linked.'.  Sometimes a grouping is missing its associated "_importance" row, for example.  Is there another way of resolving this without assuming that all four rows are always present?

Comment: @Parseltongue  How do you determine a block?

Comment: First, locate a row with "_number" or "_slider" in the name column, and grab the text that comes before it.  In the above example, that would be "fighting_stats" and "immigrant_crime." Then, delete any row that has that text.

Comment: @Parseltongue  In the example, it is given differently.  The `_number` is 5th row, of 'name', on 4th, 3rd and 2nd, it is not `fighting_stats`

Comment: that's because the ordering doesn't matter -- what determines a group is whether it shares the same prefix that comes before an "_mc" suffix (or _slider, or _number).

Comment: @Parseltongue can u check now

Comment: Amazingly, the second one works... although I have no idea how.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would tackle this:

```
groups <- df %>% 
  mutate(grp = str_extract(name, '.*(?=_confidence|_importance|_answer|_mc|_number|_slider)'),
         sfx = str_extract(name, '(_confidence|_importance|_answer|_mc|_number|_slider)')) %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  summarize(confidence = '_confidence' %in% sfx,
            importance = '_importance' %in% sfx,
            answer = '_answer' %in% sfx,
            mc = '_mc' %in% sfx,
            number = '_number' %in% sfx,
            slider = '_slider' %in% sfx) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  gather(sfx, contains, -grp) %>% 
  filter(contains == TRUE) %>% 
  select(-contains)


df %>% 
  mutate(grp = str_extract(name, '.*(?=_confidence|_importance|_answer|_mc|_number|_slider)')) %>% 
  anti_join(groups %>% 
               filter(sfx == 'number') %>%
               select(grp))
```

At a high level, I am creating an intermediate dataframe that contains the stem and suffix of the string `name`, and using the stem to create a group, and determining which of your set list of suffixes is included in each group of stems.  Then, instead of using a `filter` on the original data frame, we are using `filter` on the intermediate dataframe and then an `anti_join` on the original dataframe.

Let's walk through it in a little more detail:

```
 mutate(grp = str_extract(name, '.*(?=_confidence|_importance|_answer|_mc|_number|_slider)'),
         sfx = str_extract(name, '(_confidence|_importance|_answer|_mc|_number|_slider)'))
```

This portion is how we split the `name` column into its component parts -- by using regular expressions.

```
group_by(grp) %>% 
  summarize(confidence = '_confidence' %in% sfx,
            importance = '_importance' %in% sfx,
            answer = '_answer' %in% sfx,
            mc = '_mc' %in% sfx,
            number = '_number' %in% sfx,
            slider = '_slider' %in% sfx) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Here we are grouping by the "stems", which I've titled `grp`, and then looking for each suffix.  This part is a little wonky, and will need to be expanded if you have more groups in your data.

```
gather(sfx, contains, -grp) %>% 
  filter(contains == TRUE) %>% 
  select(-contains)
```

Here we are transforming the data into a "long" style data frame, and only keeping the suffixes that are actually contained in each group.

That completes the intermediate data frame.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(grp = str_extract(name, '.*(?=_confidence|_importance|_answer|_mc|_number|_slider)'))
```

We first must create the `grp` column on the original data frame in order to get the `anti_join` to work.

```
anti_join(groups %>% 
               filter(sfx == 'number') %>%
               select(grp))
```

And finally, we are `anti_join`ing a filtered version of the intermediate data frame to the original data frame.  This will have the desired effect you seek, I believe.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I wanted to accept this because it's clever and clearly took a lot of work, but akrun's solution is so much more efficient.  Thanks for writing this up-- I learned a lot.

Comment: In going through this manually, this is a super intelligent strategy that is general enough to be used in lots of contexts.  Thanks again for writing it up